# How to write a SQL DELETE statement using a SELECT on a JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Morning All, I'm attempting to run the following script however I'm receiving an "ORA-00933 SQL Command not properly ended" error  Can anyone see where I have gone wrong:

```
delete tableA 
FROM tableA 
JOIN tableB
ON tableB.usi = tableA.usi
WHERE tableB.usc = 'ABC'
AND tableA.cfs = '01.01.2013'
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Not directly related, but `'01.01.2013'` is a literal and NOT a DATE. Never rely on implicit data type conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not support JOINs for a DELETE statement. You need to use a sub-query

```
delete from tableA 
where exists (select *
              from tableb
              where tableB.usi = tableA.usi
              and tableB.usc = 'ABC'
              AND tableA.cfs = '01.01.2013');
```

The full syntax of the `DELETE` statement is documented in the manual
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8005.htm#SQLRF01505

---

Note that if `tableA.cfs` is a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) column, you should not rely on implicit data type conversion. `'01.01.2013'` is a string literal not a date. Oracle will *try* to convert that to a date but this might fail depending on the NLS settings of the SQL client. It's better to use explicit ansi date literals: `where cfs = DATE '2013-01-01'` or use the `to_date()` function: `where cfs = to_date('01.01.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`.

Additionally Oracle's `DATE` column includes a time. So unless all the dates in the `csf` column have the time `00:00:00` that condition is very likely to not match anything. It's safer to use `trunc(tablea.csf) = ...` to "remove" the time part of the date column (it doesn't really remove it, it simply sets it to `00:00:00`)

Comment: Thanks!  Excellent work there and some very useful information :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethink like :

```
delete tableA
    WHERE id IN (
       SELECT a.id
       FROM tableA a
       JOIN tableB b
       ON b.usi = a.usi
       WHERE b.usc = 'ABC'
       AND a.cfs = '01.01.2013')
```